What do these kernel log USB camera messages mean?
This on a Pi 4 running Buster.
A shell script on this machine grabs an image from the attached USB camera once every two minutes using fswebcam. I keep a log of this which records whether or not the grab was successful.
I run logwatch daily with a one day range. For the first time ever, I saw the following kernel messages:
------------------- Kernel Begin ------------------------

1 Time(s): usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: HD Camera Manufacturer
1 Time(s): usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05a3, idProduct=9230, bcdDevice= 1.00
1 Time(s): usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
1 Time(s): usb 1-1.1: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
1 Time(s): usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
1 Time(s): usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
4 Time(s): uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
1 Time(s): uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (05a3:9230)

---------------------- Kernel End -------------------------

(Why are there no time stamps on the logwatch message?)
Looking at the actual kernel log (/var/log/kern.log) I see these lines:
Nov 23 01:54:14 raspsky kernel: [666944.636268] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
Nov 23 01:54:14 raspsky kernel: [666944.835585] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Nov 23 01:54:14 raspsky kernel: [666945.038675] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05a3, idProduct=9230, bcdDevice= 1.00

In my own webcam log I see this:
Sat Nov 23 01:54:14 +07 2024 KoratSky Camera Returned error 255
Sat Nov 23 01:54:14 +07 2024 KoratSky Camera Returned error 255
Sat Nov 23 01:54:14 +07 2024 KoratSky Camera Returned error 255

Apparently the camera gets disconnected from the USB bus now and then and then reconnects.
What can cause this and is there anything I can do about it?
Although I haven't seen those USB camera messages in logwatch before, I have experienced situations where the camera seems to disconnect and fails to reconnect. To handle that I have a software watchdog that monitors the file that fswebcam saves. If it fails every time over a ten minute period, the watchdog repair script reboots the Pi. This always succeeds in resuming image capture.
The Watchdog repair script runs lsusb before rebooting the Pi. Here's a recent result:
Sun Nov 24 08:35:20 +07 2024 SkyKamPi Reboot
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04a9:220e Canon, Inc. CanoScan N1240U/LiDE 30
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 051d:0002 American Power Conversion Uninterruptible Power Supply
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05a3:9230 ARC International Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

I've tried using usbreset but that didn't work.
There must be a better way.

Kernel log messages related to USB cameras indicate how the system interacts with the device. Messages like new high-speed USB device confirm the camera is detected, while uvcvideo: device initialized successfully shows the driver loaded correctly. Errors such as Not enough bandwidth or reset high-speed USB device highlight bandwidth or communication issues, often due to overloaded USB buses or faulty connections. Messages like device not responding to setup address or failed to submit URB suggest power, driver, or protocol issues. To resolve, try using a different USB port, reducing bus load, updating drivers, checking cables, or using a powered USB hub. Logs like USB disconnect simply show the device was unplugged or failed to respond.

I actually have three Pi 4s with the same USB camera connected. One of them has no other USB devices. One of them has a camera and UPS. This one has a camera, UPS and Scanner. All of them exhibit the same behavior of losing communication with the camera. I don't think it can be an overloaded USB bus. My guess is that the cameras are at fault, but don't know enough to be sure.
